# Perfect Nonlinearity of AES S Boxes

Tags: aes, s-boxes

Can someone give a clear definition of  what a perfectly nonlinear function is?  Can we say that AES s-boxes are perfectly nonlinear and why?

Comment: see Definition 2 at [Perfect nonlinear functions and cryptography](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S1071579714001208/1-s2.0-S1071579714001208-main.pdf?_tid=3521928c-d6ac-4c51-a3f9-250c694f168a&acdnat=1540581057_9ef0b330058568629db7e6faf9f5158b)

Comment: as far as I know, an $m \times m$ boolean function where $m$ is an even number can never be as nonlinear (relative to its size) as when $m$ is an odd number, so an 8x8 boolean function such as the AES s-box (there is only 1) can never be perfectly nonlinear

Comment: @kelalaka The link is apparently dead.

Comment: @pushpen.paul [little search](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/591b/c69bcb9c4ba7fafecff23ff1de45d76291b1.pdf)